# How can discord bot get how long have you been playing the game?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am writing simple Discord Bot to keep track of users' in-game time. I have figured out how to track this using `presenceUpdate` event.

I was wondering if there is some simple way to check how long user has been playing a game.

The way I am currently doing it, is find what activity from `oldPresence` is not present in `newPresence` and also has type `PLAYING`. Then I check that activity `createdTimestamp` and substract it from from `Date.now()` and get playing time in milliseconds.

Here's the code that better illustrates:

```
activityDiff(oldPresence, newPresence) {
    if (oldPresence == null) return [];

    const finishedActivites = [];
    const newActivityIds = newPresence.activities.map(a => a.id);

    oldPresence.activities.forEach(oldActivity => {
        if (oldActivity.type === "PLAYING") {
            const index = newActivityIds.indexOf(oldActivity.id);
            if (index === -1) finishedActivites.push(oldActivity);
        }
    });

    return finishedActivites;
}

const activities = this.activityDiff(oldPresence, newPresence);
const start = activity.createdTimestamp;
const end = Date.now();
const secondsPlaying = parseInt((end - start) / 1000);
```

But I have some feeling there is an easier way...?

Comment: Is there a problem?

Comment: You could cache the presence updates using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and store each user in it with the last update timestamp. How you code this is really up to you.

Comment: @MrMythical there is no problem, code works, I am just curious is there any easier way like API or some attribute in presence that I can use to easier get these values. I saw there is start and end attributes in presence.timestamps attribute, but end is always null...